# Ketal formation of ethyl acetoacetate

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

Why does the ketone carbonyl group react in preference to the ester carbonyl?

Is it something to do with the resonance occurring into the ester carbonyl from the oxygen? but how does this make the ketone carbonyl more likely to form the ketal when reacted with a diol and non aqueous acid?

[image: ethyl acetoacetate]

Comment: That resonance makes the ester less electrophilic.

Comment: Well, if ester carbonyl reacted this way the result would be orthoester not ketal. (nitpicking here :)